# class SolrContentSearchManager in namespace Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider si deprecated

Tags: sitecore-client, solr

Recently i upgraded sitecore instance from 8.1 to 9.3. SOlr5.4.1 set up was working fine with sc8.1, I was using NINJECT as DI.

now after upgrading , SOlr is causing at DI level, complaining that SolrContentSearchManager should not be used any more..I am seeing the Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.NinjectIntegration.PostNinjectSolrStartUp class is referencing this class SolrContentSearchManager .. i have this in my project Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.NinjectIntegration, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

which is causing issue. NOt getting any idea where to look to resolve.

Does anyone have faced this issue. Please let me know.
Thanks